# List SQL data by a count of a group

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope you can help me with an SQL statment that I can't seem to figure out.

I have a table with a list of visits made, with the country visited and the dates such as;

- United Kingdom, 1st Nov 2009
- Germany, 8th June 2010
- Frane, 10th September 2011
- United Kingdom, 11th october 2011

etc.

I want to extract the data so that I get a table list such as follows

Times Visited - Country list

- 23      -       United Kingdom
- 10      -       France, Germany
- 4       - Czech Republic, USA, Canada
- 1       -       Poland, Serbia, Argentina,  New Zealand

So that the data shows that I have made 4 visist to the Czech Republic, USA & Canda

And the query

```
select * from 
(
    select count(*) as "trips", country from trip_view
    group by country
    order by 1 desc
) as a
```

returns the data

- 23 United Kingdom
- 10 France
- 10 Germany
- 4  Czech Republic
- 4  USA
- 4  Canada
- etc.

So I need a kind of group on the outer SQL, but if I do the following

```
select * from 
(
    select count(*) as "trips", country from trip_view
    group by country
    order by 1 desc
) as a
group by trips
```

Then I only get 1 entry for each country.  i.e.

- 23        United Kingdom
- 10        France
- 4         Czech Republic
- etc.

So for each row I only have 1 country listed and not all of them.  i.e.  Row 2 should show France & Germany and row 3 should show Czech, USA & Canada

Any ideas how to do this in mysql?

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **[`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)** on the country column it should yield the result you want:

```
  SELECT trips, 
         GROUP_CONCAT(country) AS country 
    FROM (
           SELECT COUNT(*) AS "trips", 
                  country 
             FROM trip_view
         GROUP BY country
         ) a
GROUP BY trips
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Output:

```
TRIPS   COUNTRY
   23   United Kingdom
   10   France,Germany
    4   Czech Republic,Canada,USA
```

[**Live DEMO.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10e7b/46/0)

Comment: So simple it's brilliant!  All my years of SQL I have never come across group_concat before.  Thanks

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith there is also [**`CONCAT`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), [**`CONCAT_WS`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), they are all useful.